# how insert a new value in a jsonb postgresql array of integer

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have in my table a column with type jsonb with this value

```
'[2,4]'
```

how can I update my table to insert one or more values in this column?

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`||` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

```
select '[2,4]'::jsonb || '[5,6]';
   ?column?   
--------------
 [2, 4, 5, 6]
```